How to solve undefined property $xx in the public function __construct at a controller on Codeigniter 4.5.5
I got

undefined property $Surat when defined an object called Surat

at a controller on Codeigniter 4.5.5
This is the controller file
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\Surat;

class SuratController extends BaseController
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Surat = new Surat(); // in $this->Surat, I got undefined property $Surat
   }

}

I have use App\Models\Surat from the model file
This is the model file
<?php 
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Surat extends Model {

    public function AllKat1(){
        return $this->db->table('tb_kat1')
        ->get()->getResultArray();
    }

    public function AllKat2($id_kat1){
        return $this->db->table('tb_kat2')
        ->where('id_kat1',$id_kat1)
        ->get()->getResultArray();
    }
}
?>


I want to call function AllKat1 to get data from table tb_kat1, but I got undefined property $Surat, so I can't get data from table tb_kat1, what should I do?

The message is telling you that the property is undefined, so perhaps you should define it.

Declare the Property protected $Surat; at the beginning of your class, you make it a property of the SuratController class. Then you can then safely initialize it in the constructor.
Make changes like below
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\Surat;

class SuratController extends BaseController
{
    // Declare the property
    protected $Surat; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Surat = new Surat();
    }

    public function getAllKat1() // Example method to get data
    {
        $data = $this->Surat->AllKat1();
        return $this->response->setJSON($data);
    }
}

